# imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0; error in 3.2 sdk. How do I solve the problem?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview

I get error in 3.2 sdk. imageView.contentScaleFactor = 1.0; error: request for member 'contentScaleFactor' in something not a structure or union. How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if the function is supported by using the following construct:

```
if( [imageView respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentScaleFactor:)] ) {
    [imageView setContentScaleFactor: 1.0];
} else {
    // Function not supported, work around the issue
}
```

You could pack that into a #define macro to make usage easier.

EDIT: Missed double colon in "@selector(...)"